# Shielding electromagnetic wave

Tags: wireless

I tried putting mobile phone in a microwave oven and close it, putting the phone in a fridge, a cooker and close it,... every time the phone still can receive the call from other phone which means those devices can not shield against electromagnetic wave.

AFAIK, there is attack based on electromagnetic leakage, so at least, is there any effective and simple way to shield electromagnetic radiation?

Answer (score 4):

Use a faraday cage. I have tried it before and managed to completing shield it such that it is unable to get any GSM or wifi signal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

A link on building simple homemade faraday cages : http://www.thesurvivalistblog.net/build-your-own-faraday-cage-heres-how/